# Converting a PHP/HTML drop-down menu to radio buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, radio-button

Currently I have a loop of drop-down menus (loop is dependent on the results per page that I can define, you can see why I would use a loop), and I would like to turn the drop-down menus to radio buttons. Below is my code. Could you give me some pointers on how I could convert it?

```
if (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
    $rating = $_POST['rating'];
    $accountID = $_POST['accountID']; 

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE Spreadsheet SET rating='$rating' WHERE accountID='$accountID'");
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    ?>

<form name ="rating" method ="POST" action ="" > <?

echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'accountID' value = '" . $row['accountID'] . "' >";

?>
    <select name="rating">

        <? 

        $values = array('0 - No rating','1 - Very Bad','2 - Bad','3 - Average','4 - Above Average');

        for ($i =0; $i < count($values); $i++){
            echo "<option value = \"$i\""; 

            if ($row['rating'] == $i) {
                echo "selected=\"selected\"";
            }

            echo ">" . $values[$i] . "</option>";

        }

        ?>

        </select>
        <input type ="Submit" name ="formSubmit" value ="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     $values = array('0 - No rating','1 - Very Bad','2 - Bad','3 - Average','4 - Above Average');   


    <form name ="rating" method ="POST" action ="" >
     <?
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'accountID' value = '" . $row['accountID'] . "' >";
     for($i =0; $i < count($values); $i++)
    {
    ?>
     <input type="radio" name="rbl" value="<?php echo $row['rating']; ?>" id="rbl_<?php echo $i; ?>" <? if($row['rating'] == $i) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>

<label for="rbl_<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $value[$i]; ?></label>


     <? } ?>

            <input type ="Submit" name ="formSubmit" value ="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Thanks "Dev"

Do I take your line of code and insert it somewhere in mine and test it? Is there anything else I need to edit/insert/delete/add?

EDIT: Oh I think I know how to use this.

Comment: do u mean, you succeed in ur task ?

Comment: Nope, I think the issue is I don't know where to put it.

Comment: initialize arrays which are static at the beginning of code. initializing inside loop causes server to slow down on real time if no of visitor increases.

Comment: Thank you: Do I ignore

<form name ="rating" method ="POST" action ="" > <?

echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'accountID' value = '" . $row['accountID'] . "' >";

?>
    <select name="rating">

        <? 

Or keep them? I am asking this because I noticed the removal of </select>

Comment: u don't need that </select> as your requirement is remove drop down list and put radio button there. and if possible change things here. put <form> before while loop(to avoid creation of multiple forms), and instead of using submit button use jquery to update the rating.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers :)

EDIT: I will accept your answer as soon as I can get it to work on my end. Thank you.

Comment: $values[$i] seems to not show up at index.php, therefore the radio buttons have no labels.